# javascript es6 class prototype chain modify

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6, prototype

I am trying to add class C to the prototype chain of class B

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 'a';
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.b = 'b';
  }
}

class C extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.c = 'c';
  }
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(B.prototype, C.prototype);

var a = new A();
var b = new B();

console.log(b instanceof C);
console.log(b instanceof A);
console.log(b.c);
```

The problem with the code is that `super()` call in the constructor of class B does not call the constructor of class C so the property c doesn't get added to the object. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

`super` in the constructor is based on the classes prototype (not the classes prototype property's prototype):

```
 Object.setPrototypeOf(B.prototype, C.prototype);
 Object.setPrototypeOf(B, C);
```

That way you also get proper static method inheritance.